# How to pivot categorical variable in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

How to pivot this data?

```
date - low - up
 d1  - a   - A
 d1  - b   - B
 d2  - c   - C
```

into this

```
low    a - b - c
date   
 d1    A - B - NaN
 d2   NaN-NaN- C
```

I'm using pivot_table/pivot, but it always asking for numerical.
How to pivot categorical variables? Thanks

Comment: can you please post reproducible data so we can keep this question, otherwise if not it's not reproducible and is likely to be closed as unclear/irreproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pandas version `0.15.2` I don't see any problems:

```
import pandas as pd
# I copied your example data and then read it in with
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=r'\s+-\s+')
df
Out[3]: 
  date low up
0   d1   a  A
1   d1   b  B
2   d2   c  C

df.pivot(index='date', columns='low', values='up')
Out[5]: 
low     a    b    c
date               
d1      A    B  NaN
d2    NaN  NaN    C
```

If this code doesn't work for you you should check your pandas version with `pd.version.version` and consider upgrading if you're a few releases behind.

Comment: How? I also use that version, and what I got is
`ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

The index itself is duplicate right?

Comment: I think that's a sign that your actual data is more complicated than the example you've posted, I can only work with what you give me.