# Reshaping and Pivot Tables - ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe `df` has the following structure:

```
product_id  url                 type
0   2013367 7405e0c483323f78b   A
1   2013367 ea919d2276f60f31e   B
2   452998  117312244aa203a03   A
3   452998  1a6a41a6141235d68   B
4   2196333 cd66f91431fbae2d4   A
```

I am trying to use pandas `pivot` function to restructure the dataframe like so:

```
product_id   A                  B
2013367      7405e0c483323f78b  ea919d2276f60f31e   
452998       117312244aa203a03  1a6a41a6141235d68   
2196333      cd66f91431fbae2d4  NaN
```

Follwoing the docs(https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/reshaping.html) I use `df.pivot(index="product_id", columns="type",values='url')`

However, I get the following error:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

I found a similar problem here ([How to pivot categorical variable in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29070423/how-to-pivot-categorical-variable-in-pandas)) where the solution involves a conversion to datetime-format. However, I am not using dates as index.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I just figured out that the problem was due to fact that there were product_id's in my dataset that are associated with type A multiple times. Like so:

```
product_id  url                 type
0   2013367 7405e0c483323f78b   A
1   2013367 ea919d2276f60f31e   B
2   452998  117312244aa203a03   A < ---- same id and type but different url
3   452998  1a6a41a6141235d68   A < ---- same id and type but different url
4   2196333 cd66f91431fbae2d4   A
```

Hence pandas did not know which value to assign, causing the above error to show up.

The solution was to use `drop_duplicates` prior to `pivot` like so: `df.drop_duplicates(subset=["product_id","type"],inplace=True)`