# Pivot - Transpose columns by duplicates pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, transpose

I have a DataFrame with a column named 'ID' that has duplicate observations. Each 'ID' row has one or more 'Article' values columns. I want to transpose the whole dataframe grouping by 'ID' adding new columns at the same row of a unique 'ID'.

What I have:

```
ID  Article_1   Article_2
1   Banana      Coconut
2   Apple       Strawberry
1   Apple   
3   Tomatoe 
1   Pineapple   
2   Banana  
4   Apple   
5   Apple       Strawberry
3   Apple
```

What I want:

```
ID     Article_1    Article_2   Article_3   Article_4
0001    Banana      Coconut     Apple       Pineapple
0002    Apple       Strawberry  Banana      NaN
0003    Tomatoe     Apple       NaN         NaN
0004    Apple       NaN         NaN         NaN
0005    Apple       Strawberry  NaN         NaN
```

NEW EDIT:

I had some situations where order is important.

My DF:

```
ID  Article     Article_2
1   Banana      NaN
2   Apple       NaN
1   Apple       Coconut
3   Tomatoe     Coconut
1   Pineapple   Tropical
2   Banana      Coconut
4   Apple       Coconut
5   Apple       Coconut
3   Apple       Pineapple
```

Output with first @Erfan solution:

```
        Article_1   Article_2   Article_3   Article_4   Article_5   Article_6
0001    Banana      Apple       Pineapple   NaN         Coconut     Tropical
0002    Apple       Banana      NaN         Coconut     NaN         NaN
0003    Tomatoe     Apple       Coconut     Pineapple   NaN         NaN
0004    Apple       Coconut     NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
0005    Apple       Coconut     NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

What i need:

```
        Article_1   Article_2   Article_3   Article_4   Article_5   Article_6
0001    Banana      Apple       Pineapple   Coconut     Tropical    NaN     
0002    Apple       Banana      Coconut     NaN         NaN         NaN
0003    Tomatoe     Apple       Coconut     Pineapple   NaN         NaN
0004    Apple       Coconut     NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
0005    Apple       Coconut     NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

I can't have Article_5 with a NaN value and Article_6 with a value at the same row.

Comment: Please derive your expected output out of your example dataset, where did `Coconut` and `strawberry` come from?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29070423/how-to-pivot-categorical-variable-in-pandas
df.pivot(index='ID', columns='Article', values='Article')

Comment: Is the order important for you? So for example row with `ID 0001`, does it matter that `Coconut` is in the 2nd column

Comment: Order doesnt really matter, but it can't be NaN value in 'Article_2' and value at 'Article_3'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If order of the articles is not important, we can use `DataFrame.melt` to unpivot your articles to rows.

Then we use `DataFrame.pivot_table` to aggregate to each `ID`. While we use `GroupBy.cumcount` to give a unique identifier to each `article` within a `ID`:

```
dfn = df.melt(id_vars='ID', value_vars=['Article_1', 'Article_2'])
dfn = dfn.pivot_table(index='ID', 
                      columns=dfn.groupby('ID')['value'].cumcount().add(1),
                      values='value',
                      aggfunc='first').add_prefix('Article_').rename_axis(None, axis='index')

     Article_1   Article_2   Article_3 Article_4
0001    Banana       Apple   Pineapple   Coconut
0002     Apple      Banana  Strawberry       NaN
0003   Tomatoe       Apple         NaN       NaN
0004     Apple         NaN         NaN       NaN
0005     Apple  Strawberry         NaN       NaN
```

Comment: I had a some situations where order is important.